# OpenGL toolset for new Java/Clojure project in 2011

Tags: java, opengl, clojure

I'm looking at starting a small OpenGL game project in Java/Clojure and trying to determine the best toolset for my needs. I have some experience with JOGL a few years ago but can see that the space has developed considerably since then.

My main requirements are:

- Access to the OpenGL libraries directly (i.e. direct rendering, not being forced to use a scene graph)
- Ability to use the library in both Java and Clojure
- Tools for the typical common tasks like loading a texture file etc.
- Reasonably well maintained with an active community

The following would be a bonus, but not essential:

- A lightweight, customizable game engine with some sort of physics support
- A properly maintained Maven repository that can handle the native components
- Ability to develop for mobile (especially Android)

What library/toolset would you recommend?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try LWJGL http://www.lwjgl.org

Comment: Penumbra (mentioned by Glen) is an excellent Clojure-only choice. As it takes LWJGL and makes it a bit more Clojure-esque, but for what you want, LWJGL is the way to go.

Comment: Accepting this answer as I've had good results using LWJGL with Clojure directly - thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Worth checking out is penumbra [1] which is a wrapper around OpenGL (using LWJGL) that provides a nice lispy syntax for OpenGL calls.

[1] https://github.com/ztellman/penumbra

Comment: +1 since it's worth checking out. It won't help him with his Java needs but still penumbra is a excellent framework.